# How to fix this maven dependency hell

Tags: java, git, maven

We have a Java 8 maven project that became pretty large in the last months and the build became complicated (faulty).

The structure currently looks something like this:

```
git repo 1:
    module 1:
        sub-module A
            depends on: sub-module C
        sub-module B
            depends on: sub-module A

git repo 2:
    module 2:
        sub-module C
        sub-module D
            depends on: sub-module A
```

Here's the current build process when starting with an **empty** `.m2` maven directory:

- First, `clean install` module 2 (fails on sub-module D).
- Then `clean install` module 1, `clean install` module 2 again.

I don't really know the name of this kind of problem or what are the standard solutions to approach this. 
The goal would be to be able build the project in one step.

Should we merge the two git repositories and create a big maven module for module 1 and 2?

Comment: Avoid always cyclic dependencies.

Comment: As @AndrzejJozwik said, this is called _cyclic dependencies_, and should always be avoided. How to avoid it, and how to restructure your dependencies is too broad and cannot be answered without having a deep understanding of your projects and modules.

Comment: But as a general advice: Extract those elements inside A that D is depending on to an own project - name it Z. You now can depend A -> Z and D -> Z. Cycle is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have circular/cyclic dependencies where repo1 depends on repo2 and repo2 depends on repo1, which is obviously a bad idea.

Your two options are:

1. Put your "library" modules (module A and C) into their own, separate, git repositories to remove the circular dependencies (aka chicken-or-egg problem)
2. Have a single (monolith) multi-module build for everything

There's pro's and con's to both approaches